# fetching gmail contacts using php google-api-php-client-0.6.0

Tags: php, google-api

i am implementing gmail contacts fetching using google-api-php-client-0.6.0

```
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $req = new Google_HttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=9999&alt=json");
  $val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);
  // The contacts api only returns XML responses.
  //$response = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody()));
   print_r(json_decode($val->getResponseBody())) ;

  // The access token may have been updated lazily.
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
```

with this HTTprequest iam getting user details results as below

```
[0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [$t] => http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sivagopaltech%40gmail.com/base/1301bd0ce878b5
                            )

                        [updated] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [$t] => 2011-10-10T04:40:56.311Z
                            )

                        [category] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [scheme] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind
                                        [term] => http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact
                                    )

                            )

                        [title] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [type] => text
                                [$t] => 
                            )

                        [link] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo
                                        [type] => image/*
                                        [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/sivagopaltech%40gmail.com/1301bd0ce878b5/1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg
                                    )

                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [rel] => self
                                        [type] => application/atom+xml
                                        [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sivagopaltech%40gmail.com/full/1301bd0ce878b5
                                    )

                                [2] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [rel] => edit
                                        [type] => application/atom+xml
                                        [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sivagopaltech%40gmail.com/full/1301bd0ce878b5/1318221656311001
                                    )

                            )

                        [gd$email] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other
                                        [address] => jagadeesh.miriyala@gmail.com
                                        [primary] => true
                                    )

                            )

                    )
```

where $t and others are unexpected in my opinion and in this case iam getting user emailids

when i changed the code and httpRequest as below iam getting usernames only not emailid

```
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $req = new Google_HttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=9999");
  $val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);
  // The contacts api only returns XML responses.
  $response = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody()));
   print_r(json_decode($response)) ;

  // The access token may have been updated lazily.
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
```

and the user detail format is like this

```
[title] => 96 76 36 78 07 chakri        // username
                    [link] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo
                                            [type] => image/*
                                            [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/sivagopaltech%40gmail.com/826b6c0fa89181/a9haUsi43SXQrgy78Gjg4Q
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo
                                            [type] => image/*
                                            [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/sivagopaltech%40gmail.com/826b6c0fa89181
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [rel] => self
                                            [type] => application/atom+xml
                                            [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sivagopaltech%40gmail.com/full/826b6c0fa89181
                                        )

                                )

                            [3] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [rel] => edit
                                            [type] => application/atom+xml
                                            [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sivagopaltech%40gmail.com/full/826b6c0fa89181/1349307874947993
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )
```

can any one suggest me how can i avoid those $t variables or how to get the emailid's with the second httprequest

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how simplexml formats the response. it drops the email fields. add "?alt=json" to the end of the api call and it will return a json. json_decode the response and you will have a nice php object with the emails